# iPad calendar only sees 2 of 4 GMail calendars, what have I configured wrong?

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, google-calendar

I have 4 calendars in my GMail Calendar account, two of these have been imported, they are shared by other people.

Basically, I have this:

- My personal calendar
- Week numbers for norway (since GMail Calendar doesn't show week numbers)
- One imported from an organization I have some work for
- One with TV Shows I follow every week

When I connect my GMail account on my iPad, the first, and the third, is shown, but not the second, nor the fourth. I'd like the fourth as well on my iPad.

I've looked through the configuration for all the calendars on my GMail account, but I can't see anything that differs from the one that is listed, and the one that isn't.

What else should I look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up a CalDAV account to sync all your Google calendars. The following information is provided by Google and can be found [here](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=151674):

> To sync with your device, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open the **Settings** application on your device's home screen.
> 2. Open **Mail, Contacts, Calendars**.
> 3. Select **Add Account...**
> 4. Select **Other**.
>
>    Select **Add CalDAV Account**.
>
>    Enter your account information:
>
>    - In the **Server** field, enter [ google.com ]
>    - In the **Username** field, enter your full Google Account or Google Apps email address.
>    - In the **Password** field, enter your Google Account or Google Apps password.
>    - In the **Description** field, enter the name you'd like to appear on the account.
>
>    Select **Next** at the top of your screen.
>
> After you've completed setup, open the Calendar app on your device and syncing will automatically begin.
>
> By default only your primary calendar will be synced to your device. You can sync additional calendars by visiting the following page from any web browser:
>
> - **https://www.google.com/calendar/iphoneselect**
>
>   (Google Apps users can go to **https://www.google.com/calendar/hosted/*your_domain*/iphoneselect**, replacing 'your_domain' with your actual domain name.)
>
> Select the calendars you'd like to sync, and click **Save**. The selected calendars will display on your device at the time of the next sync.